# How to get the content of django form.errors?

Tags: django

```
forms.py

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=16,
                           error_messages={'required': u'please input username',   'min_length': 'username is too short',
                                           'max_length': 'username is too long'})
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=16,
                           error_messages={'required': u'please input password', 'min_length': 'password is too short',
                                           'max_length': 'password is too long'})
```

---

```
views.py

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print form
            return HttpResponse("success")
        else:
            print form.errors
            return HttpResponse("error")
    else:
        return render(request, "register.html")
```

In views.py, I need to get the content of errors, for example "please input username", "password is too short", 
however, the form.erros are html sections , you can refer to the picture.

[image]

Comment: did you check `form._errors`?

Comment: they are not. `form._errors` is an object subclassed from list and thus it could be iterated. It has custom methods to render html/text, but you should be able to check actual error messages (eg by iterating it)

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404377/questions-about-django-form-errors-to-get-the-raw-error-messages/23404457?noredirect=1#23404457

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
def clean_username(self):
    if len(username)<1:
        msg = u"Please enter username."
        self._errors["username"] = self.error_class([msg])
        return False
    return self.cleaned_data["username"]
def clean_password(self):
    if len(password)<6:
        msg = u"Password is too short."
        self._errors["password"] = self.error_class([msg])
        return False
    return self.cleaned_data["password"]
```

For details, please check here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Answer (score 0):

Just update the code with the ipython repr.
see for reference https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html

```
views.py

def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print form
        return HttpResponse("success")
    else:
        print form.errors
        error = repr(form.errors)
        return HttpResponse(error)
else:
    return render(request, "register.html")
```