# Questions about django form.errors, to get the raw error messages

Tags: python, django, forms

The django document says 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors

Access the errors attribute to get a dictionary of error messages:

> > > f.errors
> > >       {'sender': ['Enter a valid email address.'], 'subject': ['This field is required.']}

However, when I try to print forms.errors, I got html code.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, r"login.html")
    else:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("valid")
        else:
            print form.errors
            return HttpResponse("Invalid")
```

---

```
Django version 1.6.4, using settings 'test_proj.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

<ul class="errorlist"><li>username<ul class="errorlist"><li>Ensure this value ha
s at most 3 characters (it has 6).</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I need to get the raw errors to show an ajax messager, for exemple

```
response_json = {"status": "error", "content": "Username is too short"}
```

If there is any other way to get the raw error messages, You can also tell me.Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simply an artefact of calling `print`: that implictly converts to a string, and the ErrorList class's [`__str__` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/utils.py#L79) calls its `as_ul` method to output as HTML - this is so you can output the errorlist in a template simply by doing `{{ form.errors }}`.

The contents of the object itself are not in HTML, and you can see it by doing `print repr(form.errors)`.